# Swapping between Listeners in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, button, listeners

I'm having problems dealing with **a button** and its **two listeners**. 
My objective is swapping two listeners of a button using it.
It's not the behaviour I need. I need to release the button, and then click it again in a different way (with a different listener).
So..  I "onTouch" this button, and when I release my finger, I need to swap its "onTouch" listener to an "onClick()" one.

Now, I tried to accomplish my goal doing the following:

```
 final View.OnClickListener play_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { Utility.playRecording(mediaPlayer); } };

 final View.OnTouchListener rec_listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (Utility.checkPermission(view.getContext())) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Utility.startRecording(recorder, output_formats, currentFormat, file_exts, timer);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Utility.stopRecording(recorder, timer);
                    //disabling my onTouch Listener
                        recplay_button.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    //Setting a new listener for the same button
                        recplay_button.setOnClickListener(play_listener);
                    //Changing its color.
                        recplay_button.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.coloranimreverse));
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                Utility.requestPermission(view.getContext());
            } return false; }};
```

So, the swapping works but I can't get the reason why after setting the onClickListener it also execute it, playing the sound I set in the other listener. Does the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP counts as a click?

Do you know how can I get through this? What I need is just not execute the onClick() listener in the same moment that I set it in the OnTouch() listener.

Thank you all.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly, or why exactly you're doing it like this, but if don't want the `OnClickListener` to fire after the `ACTION_UP` event, `return true;` in that `case`.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. What I'm trying to do is to associate different mode of clicking that button to fire different actions.

Comment: Ontouch click -> record my media. After that, onclick -> play my media

Comment: OK, I think I get ya now. Yeah, just `return true;` there instead of the `break;`, and I believe it'll do as you're wanting. FWIW, you could do it all in the `OnTouchListener`, just keeping some sort of flag variable for the current state. Just FYI. Cheers!

Comment: It works, thank you so much! I just did what you said and everything works properly now, can you explain me why?

Comment: Returning `true` from `onTouch()` means you've consumed the event there, and the `View` won't then try to handle it itself, which, in this case, would be to perform its click.

Comment: If you write an answer I can accept it as the one who solved my issue. It's up to you. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, sure, will do. It'll be a little bit, but I'll put an answer together when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OnClickListener` is firing on `ACTION_UP` because you're unconditionally returning `false` from `onTouch()`. Returning `false` there tells the `View` that you've not consumed the event, and that it should handle it, as well. In this case, it means that the `View` will perform its click handling, and now that it's got an `OnClickListener` set, that gets called. (In fact, you could've set the `OnClickListener` from the start, and would've achieved the same behavior.)

Returning `true` in the `ACTION_UP` `case` will signal that you're consuming that event there, so the `View` won't end up calling its `OnClickListener`. This might be sufficient for your use case, however, it also means that the `View` won't perform any of the other state changes it would normally do for `ACTION_UP`; e.g., changing its `Drawable`s to their *not pressed* state.

Rather than juggling listeners, and trying to decide which events to consume, and which to pass on, it might be preferable to handle everything in the `OnTouchListener`, track the current state in some sort of flag variable, and again return `false` unconditionally in `onTouch()`. In this way, we're simply "inserting" the desired behavior, and allowing the `View` to continue handling events and state as it normally would.

For example:

```
private boolean recordState = true;

final View.OnTouchListener rec_listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (Utility.checkPermission(view.getContext())) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (recordState) {
                        Utility.startRecording(recorder, output_formats, currentFormat, file_exts, timer);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (recordState) {
                        recordState = false;
                        Utility.stopRecording(recorder, timer);
                        recplay_button.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.coloranimreverse));
                    }
                    else {
                        Utility.playRecording(mediaPlayer);
                    }
            }
        } else {
            Utility.requestPermission(view.getContext());
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and now for your answer. I'll try to update my code using flags and, eventually, I'll update my question here.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Cheers!